# sudo ./jetty Stop or Start Failure

Tags: linux, jetty, sudo, pid

The jetty on our linux server is not installed as a service as we have multiple jetty servers on different ports. And we use command`./jetty.sh stop` and `./jetty.sh start` to stop and start jetty.

However, when I add sudo to the command, the server never stop/start successfully. When I run `sudo ./jetty.sh stop`, it shows

```
Stopping Jetty: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 18772: No such process
1 pids were not killed
No process in pidfile '/var/run/jetty.pid' found running; none killed.
```

and the server was not stopped.

When I run `sudo ./jetty.sh start`, it shows

```
Starting Jetty: FAILED Tue Apr 23 23:07:15 CST 2019
```

How could this happen? From my understanding. Using sudo gives you more power and privilege to run commands. If you can successfully execute without sudo, then the command should never fail with sudo, since it only grants superuser privilege.

Answer (score 1):

As a user it uses `$HOME`.

As root it uses system paths.

The error you got ..

```
Stopping Jetty: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 18772: No such process
1 pids were not killed
No process in pidfile '/var/run/jetty.pid' found running; none killed.
```

... means that there was a bad pid file sitting around for a process that no longer exists.

Short answer, the processing is different if you are root (a service) vs a user (just an application).